# How to understand android device is a DECT phone?

Tags: android, settings

As the title implies I need to find out if the android is installed on a DECT Phone. This is required(but not vital) for my application to proceed.

I tried almost all Build class static members including BRAND, MODEL, MANUFACTURER etc. but gained no success.

Any ideas?